# Как добавить JScrollPane к JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

Как можно добавить JScrollPane к JLabel? Добавил через add(new JScrollPane(label, две константы)), но скролл не работает (сама иконка как бы есть, но не реагирует на нажатия).

Comment: что вы хотите получить в результате? зачем к JLabel добавлять JScrollPane?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, скажем, вывести информацию для пользователя с возможностью вертикальной прокрутки

Comment: почему вы ее хотите в JLabel (предназначена для коротких сообщений)  выводить? почему не в JTextArea?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, разве она (JTextArea) не предназначена для редактирования и ввода текста?

Comment: она предназначена для текста большого объема, редактирование можно выключить - `setEditable(false)`